# SQL ORDER BY, get negative values at the end of the list

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tried to find a solution for a custom order by functionality.

I have a table which can be simplified as this with a text field and a integer category value:

```
text      | category
----------------------
'Item 1'  | 3
'Item 2'  | -1
'Item 3'  | 2
'Item 4'  | -1
'Item 5'  | 3
'Item 6'  | 1
```

The integer value -1 signals that the category is not used.

What I want to do is to sort by category and get the -1 values at the end, eg. a result like the following:

```
text      | category
----------------------
'Item 6'  | 1
'Item 3'  | 2
'Item 1'  | 3
'Item 5'  | 3
'Item 2'  | -1
'Item 4'  | -1
```

I can not touch the data stored in the database for this and I want to avoid stored procedures.

I'm using Postgres 9.2.

I have tried to create an online test here:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6pTQgKyiJYQwHBjrx8rSWZ/0#&togetherjs=PCph5kuFn1

SQL to create test table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_order
(
text text,
category integer
);
INSERT INTO test_order values('Item 1',3);
INSERT INTO test_order values('Item 2',-1);
INSERT INTO test_order values('Item 3',2);
INSERT INTO test_order values('Item 4',-1);
INSERT INTO test_order values('Item 5',3);
INSERT INTO test_order values('Item 6',1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres treats NULLs highest as default, so this will work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_order 
ORDER BY NULLIF(category, -1), text;
```

If you want to sort descending Standard SQL's NULLS FIRST/LAST is also supported:

```
ORDER BY 
   NULLIF(category, -1) DESC NULLS LAST, text
```

Regarding DISTINCT ON, you have to use the same expression in DISTNCT and ORDER:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (text,NULLIF(category, -1)) text,category 
FROM test_order 
ORDER BY NULLIF(category, -1) NULLS LAST, text;
```

See [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/awJ2evCpa1StiWZuWhWL8V/0)

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple keys in the `order by`:

```
order by (category >= 0)::int desc, category asc
```

When you convert a boolean to an integer, "true" has the value of "1" and false "0".  Hence the use of `desc` for the `order by`.

Comment: A really elegant solution, but I could not get it to work when I tested it with my real query, with a unique requirement as well:
SELECT DISTINCT ON (text,category) text,category FROM test_order ORDER BY category, text;

Adding your magic:
SELECT DISTINCT ON (text,category) text,category FROM test_order order by (category >= 0)::int desc, category asc, text;

I get the following error message:
ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON (text,category) text,category FROM test_o...

(The real table I use have more columns.)

Comment: @spist_opp . . . I would really suggest that you ask another question.  That is not the question you asked here.  But the answer to your question is that you should use a subquery -- one for the `distinct on` and one for the final ordering.

Comment: works well, https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dPVhSRGo8wd6KsWmYm33Fd/0 but empirically seems a little slower

Answer (score 0):

Other option is using *UNION ALL*

```
(select * from test_order
where category >= 0
Order By category)
UNION ALL
(select * from test_order
where category = -1)
```

The first select just is sorting by an *order by* operator. Then we are adding remaining rows where *category = -1* to rows from the first select.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the rows will be returned in the expected order.

Comment: @dnoeth, could you explain me please, why is it?

Answer (score 0):

For **SQL Server** you can use the following query:

```
SELECT tor.texts, tor.category
FROM #test_order AS tor
ORDER BY REPLACE(tor.category
           , -1
           , (   SELECT MAX(category) + 1
                 FROM #test_order))
  , tor.texts;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the category is -1, give it the max value.

[Updated fiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6pTQgKyiJYQwHBjrx8rSWZ/5)

```
SELECT
            O.text,
            O.category
    FROM
            test_order O
    ORDER BY
            CASE
                WHEN category = -1 THEN 2147483647
                ELSE category
            END,
            text;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NULLIF(category, -1) as nulled_category, * 
from test_order 
ORDER BY nulled_category ASC nulls last, text;
```

This is something that the DBA should have handle when he designed the database.